# How I get respone text in application and bind to the label in cross ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am calling the web service from other domain using Ajax call and I want to get returned response from server in my application by using following code I get response text in firebug but not in my JavaScript code. Control are not showing success and error response it goes out directly.

I want response in my success or error section but both not handling in this.
I am trying lot but not finding any solution please any one help me.
I am in a trouble. I hope somebody can help me for calling cross domain web service by using Ajax call. I am trying from 1 week but didn't find any solution till. I am getting response on browser but not getting it on my actual code.
My JavaScript code.

```
    crossdomain.async_load_javascript(jquery_path, function () {
              $(function () {
                  crossdomain.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                     url: "http://192.168.15.188/Service/Service.svc/GetMachineInfo?serialNumber="+123,                
                      success: function (txt) {
                          $('#responseget').html(txt);
                          alert("hii get");
                      }
                  });

                  crossdomain.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://192.168.15.188/Server/Service.svc/GetEvents/",
                     // data: "origin=" + escape(origin),
                      success: function (txt) {
                          $('#responsepost').html(txt);
                          alert("hii post");
                      }
                  });
              });
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply ignore the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There are only three solutions to fetch an answer from a web-service coming from another domain :

- do it server-side (on your server)
- let the browser think it comes from the same domain by using a proxy on your server
- change the web service server, by making it [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or (much cleaner today) by adding [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control)